# d3js - Create a server side SVG with javascript actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I'm trying to enable javascript code to be invoked on an action bounded to an SVG element created in **NodeJS** using d3@3. 
Unfortunately, the on('click')  is not rendered.

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    const dom = new JSDOM();
    var svg = d3.select(dom.window.document.body)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

    svg.insert('rect') 
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .on('click', function() { console.log('click')});

    svgStr = dom.window.document.body.innerHTML;
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');
    res.send(svgStr);
})
```

Output:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="200" height="200"> 
</rect></svg>
```

Where's the on('click') ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

```
`
//...
.attr("height", 200)
.attr("onclick" , "console.log('click')")`
```

for you click

and remember actions is not allowed from images to page